# I have updated to Angular 8 but my ngStyle is not updating when changing CSS classes

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I have a layered style like this:

`[ngStyle]="columnStyleArray[i1][i2].style"` which applies to a component in `*ngFor.`

Which I change with two-way binding.

So far in Angular 7 this works fine but when I upgraded to Angular 8 it doesn't work anymore. Weirdly after resizing the browser the new CSS applies and becomes visible.

Not sure if this is an Angular 8 bug or I overlooked something.

Tried to change settings
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

```
<div class="template-container" *ngFor="let section of mailtemplateArray; let i1 = index">
<div [ngStyle]="sectionStyleArray[i1].style"></div>
</div>
```

No error codes whatsoever but the CSS only applies after the windows resizes

Comment: Could you show me the content of the following attribut :   **columnStyleArray[i1][i2].style** ?

Comment: style = {
      'background-color': '',
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
      'background-size': '100%',
      'background-url': ''}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `columnStyleArray[i1][i2].style` is not a style object(`{ styleName: 'styleValue' }`), you seem to be using the wrong syntax. Try with this:

```
[ngStyle]="{ propertyName: columnStyleArray[i1][i2].style }"
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-style-correct-syntax?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: The OP's syntax is correct as long as the expression `columnStyleArray[i1][i2].style` returns key-value pairs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#description.

Comment: It probably _is_ a style object, since it worked for the OP with Angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `ChangeDetection` strategy. To me it sounds like you are not triggering a DOM update because you are mutating your object, and the `OnPush` strategy is strictly looking for immutable changes.

If changing the strategy is working, you can either update the collection immutably (wording ?), or you can trigger a DOM update using the `ChangeDetectorRef` method `detectChanges`.

Comment: No unfortunate ChangeDetection set to default or OnPush is not working. Trying to trigger it manually also does not work.